# Drawing bar chart with x axis label only visible in legend?

Tags: bar-chart, charts

I want to draw a bar chart with x axis label empty and the color of the filling reflecting the axis label from legend. Similar to this one here. [image]

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, titlepage]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./Figures/}}

\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
%\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
\usepackage{dirtree}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newcommand{\courierword}[1]{\textsf{\itshape #1}}{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}

\setkomafont{sectioning}{\normalcolor\bfseries}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ylabel=Time(s),
]
\addplot[ybar]
    coordinates{(Make Clean,14)};
\addplot[ybar]
    coordinates{(Gradle Clean,16)};
\legend{Make Clean, Gradle Clean}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could complete your code and make it compilable by including the 'documentclass' that you are using, as well as relevant packages.

Comment: It doesn't compile as of now. There are errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand what you want to do:
    \documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ylabel=Time(s),
    ymin=0,
    xtick=\empty,
    enlarge x limits={abs=\pgfplotbarwidth/2},
    ybar=-\pgfplotbarwidth,% ybar must be -bar width
    x=\pgfplotbarwidth,
    bar width=30pt,
    legend style={
      cells={anchor=west},
      legend pos=outer north east,
    }
]
%
\addplot coordinates{(1,14)};
\addplot coordinates{(2,16)};
%
\addplot coordinates{(4,10)};
\addplot coordinates{(5,6)};
%
\legend{Make Clean,Gradle Clean,Test 1,Test 2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

Comment: This is exactly how I wanted to do it. However, I want the bars to be grouped. Like, bars for Make Clean & Gradle Clean next to each other, then Test 1 and Test 2 next to each other.

Comment: I have added option `x=\pgfplotbarwidth` to get the bars next to each other.